# How do I normalize/standardize a data set to a certain set value (not average, not min, not max)?

Tags: statistics, economics, standard-deviation

I know the formulas for standardizing, normalizing, and mean normalizing (if we take the wikipedia's definition for these terms). What I want to do is to normalize to a set value. For example, if I live in Peoria, IL where the cost of living index is 1.04, then how do I normalize to 20 other cities' cost of livings (87.9, 93.9, 113, 158.3)?

Essentially, I want to know if a dollar goes so far in the area that I am used to, how much will a dollar go in the cities I might want to move to. Is this just standardizing to a z score?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the truly arcane details of cost of living indexes, the index itself is designed to answer this question.  So if the standard basket of goods  costs 100.4 for Peoria, and if that basket costs 151.3 in Chicago, then Chicago's cost of living relative to Peoria is 151.3/100.4.  Conversely, a dollar in Peoria will buy you 100.4/151.3 in Chicago.
Of course, for CPI details, go to https://www.bls.gov/cpi/